# Getting remarks of teacher and principal in view

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get the comments of teacher and principal to show up in view, all to no avail.

This is a school web app where parents get to view the results of their respective children. Just below the scores is the teacher's and principal comments.

Now, these comments show up in students' view but I'm having a hard time making it show up on the parents' view.

**This is the model:**

**Comment_model.php**

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Comment_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->current_session = $this->setting_model->getCurrentSession();
        $this->current_session_name = $this->setting_model->getCurrentSessionName();
        $this->start_month = $this->setting_model->getStartMonth();
    }

    public function TeacherComment($data) 
    {
        $this->db->insert('teacher_comments', $data);
        return $query = $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function  UpdateTeacherComment($data, $id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('teacher_comments', $data);
        return $query = $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function GetTeacherComment($student_id, $session_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        return $this->db->get('teacher_comments')->row();
    }

    public function PrincipalComment($data) 
    {
        $this->db->insert('principal_comments', $data);
        return  $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function  UpdatePrincipalComment($data, $id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('principal_comments', $data);
        return $query = $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function GetPrincipalComment($student_id, $session_id) 
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where('student_id', $student_id);
        $this->db->where('session_id', $session_id);
        return $this->db->get('principal_comments')->row();
    }
}
```

**The Controller I'm battling with:**

```
$data['teacher_comment'] = $this->Comment_model->GetTeacherComment($id, $student_session_id);

$data['principal_comment'] = $this->Comment_model->GetPrincipalComment($id, $student_session_id);
```

How do I properly put it in function?

**The view:**

```
<span> CLASS TEACHER'S REMARK: 
<u style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $teacher_comment->teacher_comment; ?> </u>
</span><br>

<br>
<span>PRINCIPAL REMARK: 
<u style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $principal_comment->principal_comment; ?></u> 
</span>
```

Comment: Most of that PHP looks unrelated to this problem (eg `TeacherComment()`, `UpdateTeacherComment()`, `PrincipalComment()`, `UpdatePrincipalComment()`) - you'll have a better chance of ppl helping if you can keep your question simple and focussed.  How are you calling the view, and passing your `$data` to it, can you edit your question and show that? Also, just to check the obvious - are you sure there *are* comments to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose this is your controller file.

```
class customview extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Comment_model");
    }

    public function yourViewFunction()
    {
        // get your $id and $student_session_id
        $data['teacher_comment'] = $this->Comment_model->GetTeacherComment($id, $student_session_id);
        $data['principal_comment'] = $this->Comment_model->GetPrincipalComment($id, $student_session_id);
        $this->load->view('your_html_view',$data); //this is the view file name without php 
    }
}
```

And now in your html view you can call like this:

```
print_r($teacher_comment); //you can view the array or object get from model
print_r($principal_comment); //you can view the array or object get from model
```

Comment: With this, I'm getting the number '1' as comments instead of the actual comments